# Postman перестал нормально обрабатывать кодировку

Tags: java

Есть `restful` сервис на **SpringBoot**. Запросы тестились **Postmanom** (для Windows). 
После автоматического обновления **Postman** параметры запроса со значениями на кирилице стали приходить на сервис кодами.
Пример:

> Postman GET [http://localhost:8080/regions?query=Пен](http://localhost:8080/regions?query=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BD) На сервис приходит
>   - `'5='`
>
> Postman GET [http://localhost:8080/regions?query=ПенBar](http://localhost:8080/regions?query=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BDBar) На сервис
>   приходит - `'5=Bar'`

Браузер эти же запросы отрабатывает нормально

Кто знает, может где-то в **Postman** можно что-то в настройках подкрутить.
 Либо как написать разрабам правильно.

Версия **Postman** - **4.7.0**

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ на сайте документации Postman.
Оказывается в нативной версии нет автоматической перекодировки url параметров.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Для перекодировки включаем редактор параметров Params.
Выделяем значение параметра. 
**ПКМ -> EncodeURIComponent**

> Parameters you enter in the URL bar or in the key/value editor will not automatically be URL-encoded. Right click on a piece of selected text, and click EncodeURIComponent to manually encode the parameter value.

[image: Окно Postman]